# Perl: How to add users from a .txt file in Linux

Tags: linux, perl

I am making a perl program that take names and usernames from a .txt file and add them as users in Linux.

ex of the .txt file formate

> ac,Chester Arthur

This is the code I have written.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

if (@ARGV != 2) {
exit;
};

my $infile = $ARGV[0];


open (FHIN, $infile) or die "Can't open input file.";
chomp (my @lines = <FHIN>);
my %users;

while (my $line = <FHIN>)
{
next if $line =~ /^[A-Z]/g;
chomp($line);
my ($username, $fullname)
    = split /\,/, $line;
$users{$username} = $fullname;
}

close(FHIN);

foreach $username(key %users)
{
    system("useradd -m $username -g groupname");
}

my $errorfile = $ARGV[1];

open(STDERR, '>', '$errorfile') or die "Can't open log";
```

Comment: Your `while` loop won't do anything because you read the contents of `$infile` into `@lines` and don't rewind to the beginning of the file. Is that your question?

Comment: Did you just copy and paste bits of code you found in different places? Do you understand what's actually going on?

Comment: Please also indent your code properly. It's important for you to be able to more easily read what you have written, but only good manners if you're asking for help with it from others

Answer (score 2):

You are a long way from having your code working, and you seem to be guessing what you should write. That's not a good way to learn to code well

This will `print` each command to STDOUT. I hope you're able to alter it so that the commands are executed instead of being printed?

```bash
perl -aF, -lne 'print "useradd -m $F[0] -g $F[1]"' users.txt
```

#### output

```
useradd -m ac -g Chester Arthur
```